# What should "value_from_datadict" method of a custom form widget return?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm trying to build my own custom django form widgets (putting them in widgets.py of my project directory).  What should the value "value_from_datadict()" return?  Is it returning a string or the actual expected value of the field?

I'm building my own version of a split date/time widget using JQuery objects, what should each part of the widget return?  Should the date widget return a datetime and the time widget return a datetime?  What glue code merges the two values together?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `value_from_datadict()` you want to return the value you expect or None.  The source in [django/forms/widgets.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/widgets.py) provides some examples.

But you should be able to build a DatePicker widget by just providing a `render` method:

```
DATE_FORMAT = '%m/%d/%y'

class DatePickerWidget(widgets.Widget):
    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None):
        if value is None:
            vstr = ''
        elif hasattr(value, 'strftime'):
            vstr = datetime_safe.new_datetime(value).strftime(DATE_FORMAT)
        else:
            vstr = value
        id = "id_%s" % name
        args = [
            "<input type=\"text\" value=\"%s\" name=\"%s\" id=\"%s\" />" % \
            (vstr, name, id),
            "<script type=\"text/javascript\">$(\"#%s\").datepicker({dateFormat:'mm/dd/y'});</script>" % id
            ]
        return mark_safe("\n".join(args))
```

Answer (score 0):

The Django source says

> Given a 
>   dictionary of data and this widget's
>   name, returns the value of this
>   widget. Returns None if it's not
>   provided.

Reading the code, I see that Django's separate Date and Time widgets are both subclasses of Input, subclasses of Widget, which appears to work with simple Strings.